# UISlider is not changing its width when I change its frame - ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have created one slider using storyboard now I am trying to change its width using this code in viewDidLoad() method :

```
var parentFrame:CGRect = self.view.frame
var currentFrame:CGRect = timeSlider.frame    // timeSlider is IBOutlet variable
timeSlider.frame = CGRect(x: currentFrame.origin.x + 20, y: currentFrame.origin.y, width:parentFrame.size.width, height: currentFrame.size.height)
```

But slider width or position is not changing & I do not want to create new UISlider programatically, I want to use existing Outlet and change its width at runtime. So any ideas Why this code is not working ?

P.S. - Actually I want to change slider width according to device size but want to keep UISlider in storyboard (don't want to create it Programatically in viewDidLoad also it should support iOS 7 is it possible?)

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) it should automatically update view when I change frame..

Comment: why do you call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`? Do you use autolayout? If so, it shouldn't be mixed with setting frame manually.

Comment: Even if I don't call that it is not changing frame ..

Comment: & I have removed all autolayout constraint because it was creating issue in iOS 7 so not using autolayout now...

Comment: Slider's position shouldn't change with this code as you set exactly the same position (`origin`) as it already has. Maybe `timeSlider` is `nil` when you set the frame (`IBOutlet` wasn't connected)?

Comment: Outlet is connected , Also I have tried to set different origin for testing but still not working, also printed frame variable before & after the variable is changed but not showing any effect in view.. see the updated question.

Answer (score 3):

Finally Solved it by adding this line before setting frame:

```
timeSlider.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

Actually I have not added any autolayout constraint but it was adding this constraint at run time automatically so have to add this, but after adding this line I was getting warning '`cannot simultaneously satisfy multiple constraints...`', So have to remove all constraint in viewDidLoad.
So final working code without any warning:

```
var parentFrame:CGRect = self.view.frame
var currentFrame:CGRect = timeSlider.frame
self.view.removeConstraints(self.view.constraints())
timeSlider.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
timeSlider.frame = CGRect(x: currentFrame.origin.x, y: currentFrame.origin.y, width:parentFrame.size.width - 14, height: currentFrame.size.height)
```

Still I can not understand why it was adding autolayout constraint even if I have removed all of it but anyway above code solves the issue..